# Differential equation on $\Bbb R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

We have a differential equation on $\Bbb R$ of the form 
$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2}u = \chi_{[0,1]},$$ 
where $\chi_{[0,1]}$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[0, 1] ⊂ \Bbb R$. I want to find a generalized solution for this differential equation.
I also want to know that will the solution be unique?

---

**Definition:** If $\Omega$ is a domain in $\Bbb R^n$. We say that $u\in \mathcal D'(\Bbb R^n)$ is a generalized solution of $$\sum_{|\alpha|\le m} a_\alpha D^\alpha u=f(x)$$ in $\Omega.$ If $u$ satisfies
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\le m} a_\alpha \langle D^\alpha u,\phi\rangle =\langle f(x),\phi\rangle $$ for every $\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega).$  Here $f\in\mathcal D'(\Bbb R^n)$ and constant coefficients  $a_\alpha\in \Bbb R^n $.

---

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to find a solution of this problem in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Dear Thomas, I want to find its solution on R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's solve the problem in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. find $u\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$\tag{1}\langle u'',\varphi\rangle=\langle \chi_{[0,1]},\varphi\rangle,\ \forall\ \varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$$

Suppose that $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $(1)$, then for all $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$

\begin{eqnarray}
 \langle u'',\varphi\rangle &=& \langle \chi_{[0,1]},\varphi\rangle     \nonumber \\
   &=& \int_0^1\varphi \nonumber \\
   &=& -\int_0^1x\varphi'+\varphi(1) \\
   &=& \int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2}\varphi''+\varphi(1)-\frac{\varphi'(1)}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

We conclude that $\langle u,\varphi''\rangle=\langle f(x)+g(x)+h(x),\varphi''\rangle$ for all $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ where $$f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$
g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
 0 &\mbox{ if $x<1$} \\
  x-1 &\mbox{ otherwise}
       \end{array} \right.$$

$$
h(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
 0 &\mbox{ if $x<1$} \\
  \frac{1}{2} &\mbox{ otherwise}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Hence, $u=f(x)+g(x)+h(x)+ax+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is the solution for your problem.

Remark 1: To find $g$, you have to solve the equation $$\langle g,\varphi''\rangle =\langle \delta_1,\varphi''\rangle$$

where $\delta_1$ is Dirac in the point $1$. To find $h$ you do a similar thing. Remember that the [Heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function is the "integral" of the Dirac distribution.

Remark 2: If you look for a solution in $[0,1]$, then $u=f(x)+ax+b$ is the solution.

Comment: Dear Tomas, Thank you so much for giving your precious time.

Comment: You are welcome @MatHeMatCian

Comment: Is it the unique solution? If not then how will we prove it.

Comment: Note that in the beginning of the proof, I assume that $u$ satisfies the equation, and then I have concluded that $u$ must be of the form $u=f(x)+g(x)+h(x)+ax+b$, so for $u$ to solve your equation it must have this specific form.

Comment: I got it. Thank you Tomas.

Comment: Dear Tomas, sorry to bother you again, Here in above form, a and b can be any real numbers. Won't they give rise to different solutions when their values vary?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The soluton is not unique if you want a fixed solution, for example $u(x)$ is some fixed function. But on the other hand, if you think about uniqueness in the sense that $u$ has a specific form, then $u$ is unique. For example, when you solve the equation $x''=0$, the solution is unique in the sense that all solution are linear functions. In this example, is interesting to note that if you give another condition, to wit, you want the function to pass in some point, then the solution is unique in the sense that is it a fixed function.

Comment: Alright Tomas, Thank you very much.